# Using HTML5 LocalStorage for Fonts / Images / Popular Plugins

Tags: image, html, local-storage, font-face

1. Has anyone used localStorage successfully to store font files referenced by CSS? How can I implement this?
2. For images, I know I can binary encode the images in script and save into localStorage, but that would mean a very large script code. If the bloated script is loaded everytime, I don't see any real benefit. If the script is cached as a seperate file, it would be the same as caching the image file in the first place. Am I missing something or there really is no benefit is normal circumstance for localStoraging images.
3. Anyone successfully implemented localStoraging popular plugins from Facebook/Google/Twitter and willing to share which are the ones most useful/applicable for caching?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what your browser support requirements are like.

1. localStorage works in IE8+.
2. @font-face has varying support, but IE9+ supports WOFF fonts.
3. I think you'd need to base64 encode your fonts for them to work with localStorage.
4. dataUri's (required for base64'd fonts) have size limitations in IE8 (I believe it's 32k).
5. Cufon seriously sucks if you ask me. In my case it's WOFF support or nothing.

This article talks about storing images in local storage. Of course it's insanely fast:
http://www.sencha.com/learn/taking-sencha-touch-apps-offline/

As for fonts, well I'm looking at doing that myself. I'll let you know how it works out :)

Also, check out [caniuse.com](http://www.caniuse.com) for browser support:

- http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage
- http://caniuse.com/#search=datauri

Comment: A friend who works at the Guardian told me their mobile site http://m.guardian.co.uk/ uses local storage to save a base64 web font on devices - on loading the site first checks if the font exists in storage, otherwise saves it. He said they use a fairly complicated procedure to do this.

Comment: Jamund, did you have any success?

Comment: You know, I ended up going with base64-encoded WOFF fonts that I put in their own stylesheet. This was fairly cacheable and worked out. But  a year and a half later, I'm pretty burnt out on web fonts. Lots of hassle, perf. problems, not much gain, especially on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

1. From experience, I can tell you don't do it.  You can use CSS3 @fontface, but that will still give you some issues.  Most stable solution I have found is to use cufon: http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/.
2. I agree with your assessment and have explored it in detail on my own.  Cached images beat encoded images in most cases.
3. No, but can only image that this will give you much grief in cross-browser compatibility.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: (1) Cufon is still my alternative to @fontface, and possibly a good backup when fontface fails. In terms of issues of fontface, I'm not very aware of any besides FOUT which is prob addressed by Google's webfont loader.  Weird seeing the number of people trying to accomplish this. I guess it would be useful if the developer had no idea of how to sprite (combine) images. (3) Disagree. This is an enhancement for browsers who can support localStorage. Tools like modernizr / amplify help you to detect for different browsers, and you can fall back on not caching which is where you start with anyway.